# Ways to convert 4x4 grid of icons to Text

Tags: python, object-detection, image-classification

I have an image which contains a 4x4 grid of icons/labels. I can't provide the actual image but what it would look like would be similar to the image given. I would like create a python program to get an output of a 2d array similar to the 4x4 grid but the elements of the array contain the text of what the icons are called.
I'm not asking for any code implementation just ideas on how to tackle this problem. The image dimensions are and the number of possible icons are fixed.
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVddJ.jpg)

The only approach I could think of was to split the image into rows and then to individual icons and prepare a template array of all possible icons with their names as the filename. Then compare each icon against the template array until a match is found. But this approach will take a long time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I think your question is too broad. Questions that ask for general guidance regarding a problem approach are typically are not a good fit for this site.